# Why my Application.OnKey "{RETURN}" doesn't work?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in vba and i want every time that you hit Enter something happen, as the code is right known it doesn't work, please help me

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", "activo"

Public Sub activo()
Range("E6").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you haven't triggered the event handler in which the `Application.OnKey` statement is placed. Instead of using `Workbook_SheetActivate`, try to use `Workbook_Open`. This way, every time your workbook is loaded, you can call your macro on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Open(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.OnKey "{RETURN}", "Activo"

End Sub

Sub Activo()
    ' Do whatever
End Sub
```

This need to be placed in the `ThisWorkbook` object.

Quite apart from any of this, the code in your question lacks a closing statement for your event-handler, but I assume this is just a typo you've made and not a problem in the actual workbook.